# Delegating access to a class property instead of an object property

Tags: c#, .net, json

I've been trying to figure out a way to deal with property mapping and naming programmatically. The thing is that I don't want to have to change multiple portions of code to be able to extend the map. The code I have right now is like this:

```
public static class Names
{
    public const string Property = "propertyNameToBeUsedInJson";
}

...
switch(propertyName)
{
    case Property:
        user.propertyToBeMapped = json.propertyValue;
        break;
}
```

What I really wanted was to be able to have some sort of dictionary where I could do something like:

```
Dictionary<string, Action>() { {"propertyNameToBeUsedInJson", <Class of User>.propertyToBeMapped} };
```

That means I would be delegating access to a property of a Class, not to a concrete object. This way I can iterate over this dictionary and if it contains the key I'm looking for, then I just go and change the property pointed by the value.

I think that a overhead during initialization is ok, but I don't want to use Reflection on a per call basis.

The questions is: Is it possible to use the second way having in mind the statement above? If so, how should I go for it?

Comment: What is your question? Are you having some problems with the Dictionary approach?

Comment: Store PropertyInfo objects, or Action delegates perhaps? To store a delegate you need to wrap a method, not a property.

Comment: @vesan I've updated it. Yes, the question is if it's possible to use the second way maybe having some initialization overhead. The thing is I don't see how to store a reference to a class property. By using Action I can do it to an object property, but at runtime the object can change and I would have to recreate the delegate.

Comment: If all the properties are `string`, you want `Func<string>` instead of `Action`

Comment: @NickStrupat as Lasse V. Karlsen said, what I really wanted was a way to wrap a class property at initialization and to resolve the instance of the class on the call.

Comment: @HazzeK: Then you can do `Func<YourClass, string>` like this: `yourClass => yourClass.YourProperty` - that is, if it's always the same class.

Comment: @vesan seems like what I'm looking for.

Comment: @vesan To which topic does this pertains? I'd no clue where to start, that's why I think the question was so confuse.

Comment: @HazzeK: I'm not sure about the topic - you could probably look up information about: 1. C# properties, 2. C# delegates and lambdas. For example on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596516109-03-09.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarize the comments:

It is definitely possible to do it with a dictionary, but properties cannot be used quite this way. Remember that properties are just syntactic sugar so you don't have to write get/set methods yourself. The best way to get it into a dictionary is probably by wrapping it into a delegate:

```
new Dictionary<string, Func<YourClass, string>>() 
{ 
    {"propertyNameToBeUsedInJson",   
     instance => instance.YourProperty} 
};
```

Then, you would use it very easily like this (error checking omitted):

```
user.propertyToBeMapped = dictionary[propertyName](yourClassInstance);
```

This will only work if the instance is always the same class. If not, the first parameter of the `Func` would have to be some base class (maybe even `object`) and then the delegate would have to do some type-checking and conversion.